# Docker run image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

So my program has a condition like

```
While(not 'e'){ 
  ask the user to input a string
  }
```

So when I build an image for my program and try to run it via docker run  I run into an infinite loop without even getting a chance to enter in my input.

I am fairly new to docker, please can you tell me why that might be happening.

Comment: How does your `docker run` command look like? It's most likely you run the command "non interactively", so if you don't specify it docker will not attach STDIN (that's the file-handle for reading user input) even if your container runs in foreground. To attach stdin you can use the `-i` flag as described in the [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground). I always run my containers like this `docker run -ti --rm your-image-name` (`--rm` removes the container after exit and `-t` allocates a pseudo tty for a more shell-like feature-set).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's helpful to include your actual code when asking a question; your Dockerfile, the `docker run` command involved, and a minimal subset of the Go code would all be useful to understand what's going on.  The SO documentation has some tips on writing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To run a program that takes input from the terminal use

```
'docker run -I <ImageName>
```